# Menu bar in gwt

Tags: gwt, menubar

I am using MenuBar control in gwt and want to get the selected item. I read the API document [API document for MenuBar](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/MenuBar.html) but could not find any method that could help me. Please tell me the way how can I trap the selected item of the MenuBar.I want to get the selected item when the user click on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your question is Command.
http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/user/client/Command.html.

When you add an item to the menubar (or to any of its children) you specify

```
 Command helloCmd = new Command() {
   public void execute() {
     Window.alert("Hello");
   }
 };
addItem("Hello", helloCmd);
```

or

```
menuItem.setCommand(helloCmd);
```

You could also execute the command independent of any menu items:

```
 helloCmd.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why the method getSelectedItem() wouldn't work. Maybe it is because you want to have the item when the user clicks? Just create your MenuItems with a Command that asks the MenuBar which item is selected. Maybe it might even be better to use a separate command for some of your items.

Nico

Answer (score 0):

I've the same problem and solved as follow:

```
public class CustomMenuBar extends MenuBar {

    public CustomMenuBar(boolean isVertical) {
        super(isVertical);
    }

    public MenuItem getSelected() {
        return super.getSelectedItem();
    }

    public void clearSelected() {
        super.selectItem(null);
    }
}
```

and you can check it for null (if not null then clear it)